# Now() function is only showing date not time

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

So I'm making a report in Access, I call
`=Now()` and it only shows the date and not the time.  How do I fix this?

I'm using access 2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your report contains a text box where you want to display the current date and time, leave its Control Source property as simply `=Now()` and use the text box's Format property to display the date and time as you wish.

If none of the available selections offers the exact format you want, you can enter a custom format as in this example:

[image]

And this is the same report in Report View:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have also noticed reports do this.  I just change the field to be something like
    =Date() & " at " & Time()

Answer (score 0):

It depends on system date setting. Use Format(now(),"general date") in place of now(). Alternatively, you can use format(now(),"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm ampm") to show date with time in AM/PM form. You can omit "ampm" to show time in 24 hour format.